# Regex to allow alphanumeric, spaces, some special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this `^[a-zA-Z0-9 @&$]*$`, but not working for me in few cases.

If someone types

- A string that only consists of digits (e.g. `1234567`)
- A string starting with a special character (e.g. `&123abc`)

need to be rejected. Note that a special char can be in the middle and at the end.

Comment: Could you list exactly what conditions need to be rejected and why?

Comment: Should the pattern accept empty string? If not also try [`/^\b(?=\d*\D)[a-z\d @&$]+$/i`](https://regex101.com/r/B2merL/3/). It's not very clear (this pattern requires at least one character).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to need to avoid matching strings that only consist of digits and make sure the strings start with an alphanumeric. I assume you also need to be able to match empty strings (the original regex matches empty strings).

That is why I suggest

```
^(?!\d+$)(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9 @&$]*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AScqhl/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!\d+$)` - the negative lookahead that fails the match if a string is numeric only
- `(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9 @&$]*)?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]` - a digit or a letter
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9 @&$]*` - 0+ digits, letters, spaces, `@`, `&` or `$` chars
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: If i want to exclude some and include some special character, how i can exclude some, for inclusion, i see it from your regex.

Comment: @Sharpeye500: Sorry, what do you mean? If you do not want to match a char, do not add it to the character class in the first place.

Comment: If have a "." (period) in between characters, currently the regex accepts it.
For example, "Test.Work", if i need that to be rejected  "." , how do i exclude in the regex.

Comment: @Sharpeye500: [Not sure what you mean](https://regex101.com/r/AcWMcg/1),

Comment: If i type a word say, "Sharpeye500@" it is valid and correct, if i type "Sharpe.Eye500", with a dot in it, it is supposed to be invalid, however with that regex, it says valid, i want to say it as invalid when there is a dot in the word.

Comment: @Sharpeye500: I cannot understand you. A string with `.` [is not matched](https://regex101.com/r/Wcka6Q/1) with the regex above. Please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with the following regex

```
^(?!\d+$)\w+\S+
```

check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/C2DBHp/1)